# Why are the python element tree taking up so much memory?

Tags: python-2.7, elementtree, export-to-csv

I am about to find some specific information from a huge (4 GB) xml-file. To avoid using too much memory, I have used the iterparse method of the element tree library in Python. This seems to work well, and the memory usage for Python is ca. 3.5 MB for the most part. But the memory usage is increasing to several gigabytes, when it reach the end of the program, and it seems like it never will finish.

From the output csv-file, it seems like the program has been through all elements of interest, but has some problems with finishing the program. Can anybody see what is wrong with my program, and tell me why it behaves like it does?

The program is shown here:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

output_file = 'output.csv'
input_file = 'raw_data/denmark-latest.xml'

parser = ET.iterparse(input_file, events=("start", "end"))
parser = iter(parser)
event, root = parser.next()

with open(output_file, 'a', 1) as f:
  for event, element in parser:
    if event == "start" and element.tag == "node":  

      for node in element.findall(".//tag/[@k='addr:housenumber']/..[@lat]"):
        f = open(output_file, "a")
        lat = node.get('lat')
        lon = node.get('lon')

        for tag in node.findall("./tag/[@k='addr:city']"):
          city = tag.get('v')

        for tag in node.findall("./tag/[@k='addr:postcode']"):
          postcode = tag.get('v')

        for tag in node.findall("./tag/[@k='addr:street']"):
          street = tag.get('v')

        for tag in node.findall("./tag/[@k='addr:housenumber']"):
          houseno = tag.get('v')

        string = str(lat) + ', ' + str(lon) + ', ' + str(postcode) + ', ' + str(city) + ', ' + str(street) + ', ' + str(houseno) +'\n'
        f.write(string)

      root.clear()
```

Comment: Is there perhaps some kind of element above `node`, or at the same level? That might cause the `root` to grow until the next `node` is seen.

Comment: @larsmans, As far as I can see, the `node` element is always at the second level.